# jQuery UI 1.10.0 tabs with ASP.NET MVC 4: Sometimes tab is fired as anchor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

After upgrade to jQuery UI 1.10.0 the tabs are not working correctly anymore. Sometimes clicking on the tab results in refreshed window with the content of the ajax call to MVC action.
So it looks like the anchor event is called before the ui-tabs event???

HTML code:

```
...
<div id="rightTabsPanel">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab-shadow"><a href="@Url.Action("Agenda", "Home")">Agenda</a></li>
        <li class="tab-shadow"><a href="@Url.Action("Twitter", "Home")">Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="tab-shadow"><a href="@Url.Action("Buienradar", "Home")">Buienradar</a></li>
        <li class="tab-shadow"><a href="@Url.Action("FileKaart", "Home")">File kaart</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
```

My javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    $("#rightTabsPanel").tabs({
        //Replacement for cache:false 
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            if ( ui.tab.data( "loaded" ) ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }

            ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
                ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
            });
        },
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.oldTab.text() == "Twitter" || ui.oldTab.text() == "Yammer") {
                $("#slider-code", ui.oldTab).empty();
            }
            else if (ui.oldTab.text() == "File kaart") {
                fileKaartDeInitialize(ui.oldPanel);
            }
        }
    }).bind('tabsload',function(event, ui){ 
          if (ui.tab.text() == "Agenda") {
              var $this = $('#slider-code', ui.panel);

              $this.tinycarousel({ axis: 'y', interval: true, controls: false, intervaltime: 7000 })
          }
          else if (ui.tab.text() == "Twitter") {
            var $this = $('#slider-code', ui.panel);

            $this.tinycarousel({ axis: 'y', interval: true, controls: false, intervaltime: 5000 })
         }
          else if (ui.tab.text() == "Buienradar") {
            var $this = $('#slider-code', ui.panel);
        }
          else if (ui.tab.text() == "File kaart") {
              fileKaartInitialize($('.fileKaartPage'));
        }
    });

   $("#rightTabsPanel .ui-tabs-nav li").unbind();
   ...
}
```

After reading [jQuery UI 1.10 Upgrade Guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/) carefully I could fix some minor bugs in my code but the bug described above still remains.

My questions: 
 - Does anyone experience the same problems after upgrading to jQuery UI 1.10?
 - Does anyone have a solution or ideas to get this problem fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone.  I have the same issue after upgrading to JQuery 1.9.1 and JQuery UI 1.10.0 using NuGet package.  So, at least you know that the issue is not unique to your project.  The tabs render correctly, but when clicked they directly launch the url into the browser instead of retrieving content via Ajax.  I'm relatively new to JQuery, so I don't yet have the debugging background to get to the bottom of it.

Code Sample (obviously about as simple as it gets here):

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/AllWorkTab">All Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="/MyWorkTab">My Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="/PhotoTab">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/WeatherTab">Weather</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was in some other dependent javascript libraries.  Errors in the dependent library code were shorting out the JQuery execution on the page.  I believe it was the "Microsoft JQuery Unobtrusive Ajax" package that required upgrade afterward.